# image recognition - finding an object in an image from a source image

Tags: c#, image, pattern-matching

Essentially what i'm looking for is as follows.

I have 2 images. The source image contains the object I want to find within the second image 
e.g. Source image will be that of an apple, and the scene image will contain a table setting with loads of objects, one of which is an apple. The app needs to find or identify if the apple is n the scene (possibly a percentage indicating the probability of the apple being within the image)

I'm not sure which algorithm to start with and was hoping for some guidance as a starting point. I would imagine i need to use some pattern recognition on the first image to create a profile of what i'm looking for, and then image recognition to find the object in the second image?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated and if you could outline the steps needed and what libraries you recommend that would be great. It should ideally be in C#.

Comment: i think for the first image you will need to create an array of each of the pixel RBG color and then try to find the best match of this array in the other image

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: see this ftp://164.41.49.96/Usuarios/Eduardo/home_porthos/Documents/01.2008/Processamento%20de%20imagens/ImageProc.pdf